# How to upload images and use image as background image on blog post?

Tags: python, django, image

Okay so I want to be able to upload an image when I am writing a blog entry in the add post section of the admin panel and use that image as the background image of a link to that post. The anchor link is on the homepage.

What field type would be best for this? Do I need to write an extra view?

#### blog/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

#### blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, "blog/post_list.html", {"posts": posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
  post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
  return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

#### blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)


    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField. And why would you need another view?

Comment: Wasn't sure If another view was needed. I'm kinda new to MVC frameworks. @makaveli

Comment: Would `https://github.com/divio/django-filer` be a help for you? It manages image and file uploads. Files are stored in the `MEDIA` tree. It creates thumbnails and the kind for you.